# Keep multi-version of a static-lib like what we do for shared-libs

Tags: shell, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, symlink

I'm maintaining two branches of two projects:

```
Projcect LeonLog:
  master(version: 2.0.0)
  producing(version: 1.0.0)

Projcect Octopus:
  master(version: 6.0.0, depending on LeonLog:master)
  producing(version:5.0.0, depending on LeonLog:producing)
```

The projcect LeonLog yields a static library `libLeonLog.a` into /usr/local/lib/, and when I building `Octopus:master`, the version 2.0.0 of `libLeonLog.a` should be linked against, and when `Octopus:producing` being built, the v1.0.0 of `libLeonLog.a` should be used.

So I want to save two versions of `libLeonLog.a` at same time, and add a symbolic link to current version, like what we do for shared libs(`libLeonLog.so` links to `libLeonLog.so.1.0.0`).

My questions:

1. Why is there **not** any symbolic linking convention for static-libs?

   I think that the requirements like mine are very common, there must be a widely used solution.
2. How do you deal with problems like mine(to keep multiple versions of
   static-lib)?
3. How to gracefully add symbolic links for static-libs like what we have
   done for shared-libs with CMake?

I'm trying to do it by myself, like followings:

```
add_library( leonlog_static STATIC LogToFile.cpp )
set_target_properties( leonlog_static PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE  LeonLog
    OUTPUT_NAME_DEBUG    LeonLog
    PUBLIC_HEADER        LeonLog.hpp
    VERSION              ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SUFFIX               ".a.${PROJECT_VERSION}"
)

install( TARGETS leonlog_static
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)
```

And then, I’m trying to add a symbolic link by running a shell command when installing:

```
get_target_property( MY_NAME leonlog_static ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE )
message( STATUS "MY_NAME:\"${MY_NAME}\"" )
install( CODE "execute_process(
  COMMAND ln -fs ${MY_NAME}.${PROJECT_VERSION} ${MY_NAME}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} )" )
```

But I can **NOT** get the value of PROPERTY `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE`, I got a empty string.
I have also tried many other properties, but all failed.
like this:

```
get_target_property( MY_NAME leonlog_static LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE )
message( STATUS "LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE:\"${MY_NAME}\"" )
get_property( MY_NAME TARGET leonlog_static PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME )
message( STATUS "OUTPUT_NAME:\"${MY_NAME}\"" )
```

Finally, I have to compose it by myself, like this:

```
get_target_property( MY_NAME leonlog_static OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE )
# compose it with adding a prefix, but it's hard coding!
set( MY_NAME "lib${MY_NAME}.a" )
message( STATUS "MY_NAME:\"${MY_NAME}\"" )
install( CODE "execute_process(
  COMMAND ln -fs ${MY_NAME}.${PROJECT_VERSION} ${MY_NAME}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} )" )
```

I think it is very ugly, and hard to be maintained.

Is there an “Official” way to do this?
Sorry for my English!

Comment: This is pretty much why the world moved to shared libraries. Historically we would have multiple build servers to deal with that situation. Yes. It is very ugly. And hard to maintain. I'm not aware of any conventions to help. You could write your own shell scripts to perform the symbolic linking. But it's ***fragile***. Good luck!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Thanks for your hint!  It's not too hard to do the same for static-libs like they do for shared-libs, when developing CMake/make. Why they do it only for shared-libs?

Comment: Your purpose **differs** from the one of SONAME for shared libraries. Only **one version** of a shared library is **available for development** (that is, for *linking*) at any time. This is the version to which `libLeonLog.so` currently points to. At some time one could **update** the library (update != switch branches). After that development will use new `libLeonLog.so` file. But old `libLeonLog.so.1.0.0` remains on the disk, because it is used **at runtime** by already compiled executables. Static libraries are not used at runtime, so they don't need such mechanism.

Comment: If you want two variants of the library to be available for development at the same time, then assign different names for such libraries (e.g. `libLeonLog1.a` and `libLeonLog2.a`). Or place this libraries into different subdirectories (e.g. `v1/libLeonLog.a` and `v2/libLeonLog.a`). Or install project in different install prefixes (e.g. `/home/me/Leon_v1/` and `/home/me/Leon_v2/`). Symlinks are hardly useful for that purpose.